# How to use matching methods with multilevel data?

Tags: r, regression, multilevel-analysis, matching

I am very new to matching and multilevel models, so I hope my question is not too naïve.

I have a time series data set with a binary dependent variable measured at the individual level, a dichotomous treatment indicator (also at  the individual level), and a series of country-related variables I would like to include. My idea is to use multilevel models with matching to estimate the average treatment effect on the treated.

The data look somewhat like the example below. I would like to model one random intercept for year and another one for country with gdp as a predictor.

```
ID  depen age treat country year gdp
1   1     19  1     1       1999 10.01
2   1     23  0     1       1999 11.42
3   0     43  1     1       1999 12.48
4   1     27  1     1       2000 12.78
5   0     67  0     1       2000 13.22
6   1     34  1     2       1999 47.54
7   0     54  1     2       1999 47.99
8   0     22  1     2       1999 48.32
9   0     78  0     2       2000 48.55
10  1     52  0     2       2000 49.04
```

Is there any way to do it using `R` and, preferably, with matching techniques *other than* propensity score (e.g., [coarsened exact](http://gking.harvard.edu/files/gking/files/cem.pdf) or [genetic matching](http://sekhon.berkeley.edu/papers/GenMatch.pdf))? Thanks!